# Is there a listener that can call a function to move on to next set of data in Carousel (Page View)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've set up this Carousel using a PageView.builder. It displays 5 tiles at a time.

Once the user has swiped all the way over to the right & pulls on the last tile (see image)...I'd like to move onto the next set of 5 tiles in an array.

Is there an event handler for this? I've managed to set up a listener that can determine when the user has swiped **to** the last tile, but cannot figure out how to tell when they're pulling on this so it can be refreshed.

Appreciate any help I can get on this. Code below :)

[image: Pulling reverse direction. No more tiles.]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

class RecommendationPanel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _buildRecommendationPanel();
  }
}

class _buildRecommendationPanel extends State<RecommendationPanel> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 1.0);
    _pageController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_pageController.offset >= _pageController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_pageController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        //This is working in the sense that it tells when they're on the final tile
        //I want it so knows when you drag to the right
        print('Final tile');
        //I could refresh the list and then just move everything back to #1 in the view...i.e. the last card [index 4] can now shift to 5
        //_pageController.jumpToPage(0);
      });
    }
    if (_pageController.offset <= _pageController.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !_pageController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        //Need to figure out how to work this - there's going to have to be another variable checking what place in the top N recommended array it is, and then adjust accordingly
        print('Back to first tile');
        //_pageController.jumpToPage(3);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          //You may want to use aspect ratio here for tablet support
          height: 270.0,
          child: PageView.builder(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: 5,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            controller: _pageController,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
              //I could potentially call something here to update the slider index
              return _buildCarouselItem(context, itemIndex);
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 30,
          child: Center(
            child: SmoothPageIndicator(
              controller: _pageController,
              count: 5,
              effect: WormEffect(
                spacing: 8.0,
                dotHeight: 10,
                dotWidth: 10,
                activeDotColor: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCarouselItem(BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
    List<String> labels = [
      'Pub',
      'Bar',
      'Football Match',
      'Nightclub',
      'Book Festival',
      'Six',
      'Seven',
      'Eight',
      'Nine',
      'Ten',
    ];

    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
      child: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        //color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 2,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Container(
                  // In here is where I should build each individual tile
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 260,
                    child: Text(labels[itemIndex]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildIndicator(BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int count) {
    return AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
      activeIndex: itemIndex,
      count: count,
      effect: WormEffect(
        dotColor: Colors.grey,
        activeDotColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [Gesture Detector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Comment: @tomerpacific thanks! What's the best way to link this with the PageController in the code above - i.e. to trigger a refresh when horizonal swipe (Gesture Detector) AND last card in view (_pageController)?